# Extremely slow Gradle copy task

Tags: gradle, windows-7

It took me basically 33 minutes to copy 3.5Gb of files with the gradle copy task on Windows 7. It just copies the files from the Gradle local repo located in C:\users\myname\.gradle to some other directory on C:\.
When I copy the files manually, the average speed is around 8Mb/s.
i'm using Gradle version 2.3 (for compatibility with the project).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows this behavior? How much data do you copy?

Comment: I'm copying a dozen of ~300Mb files. I've relaunched it and it took 13min, and another time it took 4min. With VisualVM I can see that it takes a huge amount of time in FileInputStream.read().

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I feel like using shell command would be faster than this stupid gradle command.